Why is it not standard to include minimum practical effect size in null hypothesis?
I am a new to statistics.  I am confused by the common practice of having a null hypothesis of the form $\theta = \theta_0$ in hypothesis testing. It would seem to me that, in many cases, we are not interested in exact equality but instead $|\theta - \theta_0|< \delta$ for some threshold $\delta$ at which the difference between $\theta$ and $\theta_0$ would have practical significance.
Are there examples of researchers formulating their null hypotheses in this way?  Why is this not more common?

This is in fact very common; search for "non-inferiority" testing (and possible synonyms: inferiority testing, superiority testing, equivalence trials, etc...). The most common iterm s non-inferiority: proving that my statistic $\theta$ is less than $\delta$ lower from a "reference" $\theta_0$. CV has lots of posts on this, and Google will provide 100's of relevant sites. There is even a CV tag, found here https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/non-inferiority/info.

Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to combine your new account with your previous one.

@whuber I would prefer not.  Is it okay to have two accounts for different purposes?

It is strongly frowned upon because it creates opportunities to game the system, such as voting for yourself.

If it is merely frowned upon, rather than forbidden, I would prefer to continue with two accounts while being mindful to not vote for myself.  I am an expert in some areas of mathematics and I wouldn't feel comfortable asking extremely basic stats questions under my true identity.  My intellectual values are certainly out of alignment with my feelings here:  I would like to be brave enough to post these kinds of questions under my true identity but I am not :(

I understand.  You can combine your accounts and de-identify the resulting single account.

@whuber I value my identity on MathSE, MathOF, and MathEd.  Complete account de-identification is not an option I am willing to entertain.

FWIW basic questions $\neq$ bad questions.

Defining a minimum relevant effect size is standard practice in non-inferiority testing and in TOST (a form of equivalence testing).
As to why it isn't standard practice in all hypothesis testing, I don't have a definitive answer, but some thoughts:

When reporting the results of a hypothesis test, good statistical practice would be to involve measures of uncertainty and effect size anyway.
Properly designed studies substantiate the required sample size, which requires you to define a minimally relevant effect size as well.
Significantly non-$\theta_0$ can be a more fair way to assess significance. Suppose we are interested in whether a potential confounder has a significant effect. Rejecting a value hypothesized under the null is easier than rejecting at least $\delta$ further away.


It seems that in TOST the null hypothesis is $|\theta - \theta_0| > \delta $ and the alternative hypothesis is $|\theta - \theta_0| \leq \delta$.  The rôle of $H_0$ and $H_1$ are reversed relative to my proposal.  Cool stuff though, I had not heard of equivalence testing before.
